# Getting a prescription inhaler as a US citizen in the UK

Tags: health, london, england

I'm staying in the UK (London) until the 7th of August. I have some sort of Asthma that only presents itself when I try to exercise with hay fever. I've left my inhaler stateside and I'm wondering how to get a new one. It seems the only way to do it is privately, which isn't that big of an issue because the inhaler isn't that expensive (I don't think?). But I'm wondering how much it might cost/the easiest way to do it. I'm insured in the US if that makes any difference.

Comment: Whether you are issueed in the US is only relevant if your US insurance covers you when you are in the UK.  This is quite possible (mine does), but unlikely to be certain.

Comment: Have you considered asking someone in the US to ship it to you? Depending on how quickly you need it, two-day or even overnight shipping might be cheaper than buying in the UK (especially if you have to visit a clinic), and a lot less hassle. (I am not sure if there is a possibility of customs issues, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a walk-in clinic near the [Moorgate Tube Stop](https://tfl.gov.uk/tube/stop/940GZZLUMGT/moorgate-underground-station?lineId=northern) at which you can arrange a 15 minute consultation for GBP 55.

You can book an appointment via [their site](http://www.citydoc.org.uk/private-gp-clinic-london/?infinity=ict2~net~gaw~ar~56969125470~kw~walk%20in%20clinic%20london~mt~p~cmp~GP%20SERVICES%20%28general%29~ag~Walk%20in%20clinic%20london&gclid=CKr7iL6q6sYCFUKWtAodhQIHSA), or by telephone.  The clinic at Moorgate is given here as an *indicative sample only*, there are other walk-in clinics in central London that may be more convenient.  I have never attended that particular clinic (and have no connection to it), but have used the walk-in clinics both at Kings Cross and [Marylebone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Street).

[image]

You will need to pay and then reclaim the expense from your insurer in the US.